# useIonViewDidEnter in the menu doesn't work in ionic-react

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-react

I'm working with ionic react and I want to use `useIonViewDidEnter` in the menu component but `useIonViewDidEnter` in the menu component doesn't work and nothing showing in the console, anyone can help, please?

```js
    const ManagerMenu: React.FC = () => {
    
    useIonViewDidEnter(() => {
    console.log('isAuthorizedToSeeContracts')
    
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

It only works in pages I believe.

I suggest you manage the authState either through a property, context, or something else.

Comment: i solve it by using this function  useEffect(() => { console.log('hello') })